# syntax meaning of ' (method) alert(message?: any): void ' in 'window.alert()' in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

In `Visual Studio Code`, while making a react app when I move my cursor on `window.alert()`, I see a pop up which reads as follows:

```
alert(message?: any): void; 
(method) alert(message?: any): void
```

Please explain what it means, as I am from java background and I can't understand it. I could only understand that `alert()` is a method which returns nothing, but what about it's parameters?

What is `(message?: any)`?

Comment: That isn’t JavaScript. It is TypeScript.

Comment: VS code will offer hints based of TypeScript typings if they are available. If you're starting out in JavaScript then maybe consider starting out in TypeScript instead. Being from a strongly typed background you might find it easier to adapt to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest Java equivalent would be

```java
public void alert(Optional<Object> message){...}
```

**What does 'any' mean?**
`java.lang.Object` cannot extend primitive types, however, Typescript can with `any`.

Type `any` denotes the value can be any Object Type, including primitive types. For example it can be a primitive type such as boolean, string, or number, or any Class types such as React, Button, or JSXElement.

**What is the question mark?**
In the Javascript, the delimiter `?` means the parameter is optional.
For example, both of these are acceptable:

- alert() -- No message argument
- alert("hello") -- One argument

Comment: `any` means any value, including primitives.

Answer (score 1):

alert(message?: any): void;

`alert()` : it is a method

`message?: any =>` message is parameter which goes to alert method, ? mark suggest it is optional

`void =>` its a return type of that method